# Game center unavailable (player is not signed in )

Tags: objective-c, game-center

I am integrating game center on cocos2d project.

```
GKLeaderboardViewController* leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != nil){
    NSLog(@"view make");
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime; 
    leaderboardController.category = @"myGameBoard";

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

show popup

```
Game Center unavailable
Player is not signed in
```

and no leaderboard appeared.

My Conditions are

1)testuser looks successfully loginnd

this message appeared on screen.

```
Welcome back testuser
*** sandbox ***
```

2)then this message appeared

```
Game Center unavailable
Player is not signed in
```

3)App upload is ready and pass the validate on organizer

4)app version on itunes connect and local is the same 1.00

5)Bundle Idenfier on itunes connect and local is the same

6)leaderboardController.category name 'myGameBoard' is correctly set.

is there any other point I need to investigate??

Comment: Before moving your app to the ready state in itunes connect did it work with the test user ?

Comment: Status is 'Waiting for Upload'. I don't need to upload real binary for gamecenter test, am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, while not live your app will always work with the Sandbox servers of GameCenter. But the issue you are seeing might be due to the fact that your app is not in its initial state anymore (cannot confirm it though)

Comment: Do you authenticate the user successfully?

Comment: it shows the 'welcome back testuser' message ,so I think it is successfully authenticated...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem for **TEST MODE** in this way:

- Go to Game Center App
- Tab *Friends*
- Click *Setting*
- at the end of the screen: *SANDBOX* and *LOGGING MUST BE ON MODE*

I hope that it works for everyone

Comment: There is no SANDBOX at the end of the screen :(

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by ensuring the local user was authenticated and logged in:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (![localPlayer isAuthenticated])
    {
        [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && viewcontroller)
            {
                AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                UIViewController *currentViewController = [[appDelegate window] rootViewController];
                [currentViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        })];
    }
}
```